# Odoo fields_view_get add dynamic groups

Tags: python-2.7, odoo, odoo-10

I want to override fields_view_get of odoo to add groups to fields dynamically based on a condition.

```
@api.model
def fields_view_get(self, view_id=None, view_type='form', toolbar=False, submenu=False):
    res = super(client_quote, self).fields_view_get(view_id=view_id, view_type=view_type, toolbar=toolbar,
                                                submenu=submenu)
    """update this method to change the string of fields in different tab of client quote if it changes from vfx sheet """
    if view_type == 'form' and ('vfx_shots_ids' in res['fields']):
        for field in res['fields']['vfx_shots_ids']['views']['tree']['fields']:
            if self._context.get('quote_id'):
                vfx_quote_id = self.env['vfx.quote'].browse(self._context['quote_id'])
                field_id = self.env['field.name'].search([('name', '=', field)])
                if field_id:
                    line_id = self.env['mapping.template.line'].search([('template_id', '=', vfx_quote_id.template_id.id),
                                                                        ('field_id', '=', field_id.id),
                                                                        ('model_name', '=', 'vfx.shots')
                                                                        ])
                    if line_id:
                        string = line_id.heading_id.name
                        res['fields']['vfx_shots_ids']['views']['tree']['fields'][field]['string'] = _(string)
                        res['fields']['vfx_shots_ids']['views']['tree']['fields'][field]['groups'] = str('vfx_quote_template.group_empty_fields')
    return res
```

This is my class and fields, i want to change vfx_quote_template.group_executive_producer group based of a condition.
Currently fields_view_get code seems to have no effect.

```
class vfx_shots(models.Model):
    _name = 'vfx.shots'

    item_number = fields.Char('Item',groups="vfx_quote_template.group_executive_producer")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use lxml library to modify the XML architecture of the view in the fields_view_get() method.
You can also override the fields definition by overriding the fields_get() method.

You can get examples here : https://bazaar.launchpad.net/~unifield-team/unifield-server/trunk/view/head:/bin/addons/consumption_calculation/history_consumption.py#L457

I know it is in v6 version of the code, but the fields_view_get behavior didn't change a lot since this version.